# Comparing Packed and Unpacked arrays in Verilog

Tags: verilog

The objective in the following snippet of code is :

Compare 2 Bytes of data which are stored in the form of a packed array (2 locations, 1byte in each) to 2 Bytes of data stored in an unpacked way.

```
module byte_design (
input wire clk,
input   wire [7:0] my_data [1:0],
input   wire [15:0] other_data,
output reg temp
);

integer j;

assign my_data[0] = 8'haa;
assign my_data[1] = 8'hbb;
assign other_data = 16'haabb;

always @ (posedge clk) begin 

for ( j = 0; j < 2 ; j = j+1 ) begin 
  if ( other_data == my_data [j+:1]) begin 
    temp <= 1'b1;
  end
  else begin 
    temp <= 1'b0;
  end 
end 
end 

endmodule
```

So in the above code, according to my thought process, when j=0 other_data (16'haabb) will be equal to my_data[0:1] and result in temp=1'b1.

Testing this design gives out the error of Illegal comparison between packed and an unpacked type.

To summarize, the objective is here to compare 2Bytes of data with 2 1Bytes of data. Any suggestions/ procedure to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply compare two bytes, there is no need to loop over the packed array. This will work and is much clearer, in my opinion.

```
module byte_design (
  input wire clk,
  input   wire [7:0] my_data [1:0],
  input   wire [15:0] other_data,
  output reg temp
);

  assign temp = ({my_data[1], my_data[0]} == other_data);

endmodule
```

Example on edaplayground.com: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/CtZ

Comment: Thank you for the response. The example you have given works perfectly for 2bytes. On my side, the bigger picture involves looping through n bytes and comparing it to the 2 bytes. So I was able to use the {{my_data[j],my_data[j+1]}} logic to extend it to n bytes.